# My Website redirects to Malicious sites

Tags: malware

Good Day

I just uploaded a Wordpress theme onto my Website webserver. Now I tested this theme on my home server before with no problems.

Since it has been on the webserver (at a trusted hosting company), I get url redirects to malicious sites when I am browsing though my website. (I have never given any account details to anyone, account only a week old)

Here is my site: http://evolutionof4.co.za

The malicious sites it links to are: themeforest.net, carolini.net amongst others.

I have scanned all my files on the webserver for malware (with avast), I have also scanned my site with Sucuri Security, but it did not pick up anything.

I don't think it is malware on MY PC, since I got the same problem from another PC on my LAN...

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: themeforest.net isn't a malicious site, is a marketplace for web-component like template, snippet, psd and more.
Have you bought there your theme?

Comment: Yes. I found a redirect script in my header.php file for the theme creators to get traffic and exposure

Comment: PLEASE see my malicious script and help me verify the legitimacy thereof: thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem, I resolved it , by checking manually , all the files at the root , means those files which come with wordpress and placed in root, wp-config, wp-settings etc, there I found some melicious script in the file means the code looking encrypted. I removed it. and then check my footer.php here also some 2,3 lines of malicious code. I removed it, then I check it again the problem is same google showing it as malicious site, then I searhed it on google, and found that after removing such code you should submit your site for a review in the webmaster tools of google after a day I reciev a mail.

You check your files, after checking change your username and password of ftp and wp-admin also,

the most important is to submit a review on webmaster tool

Answer (score 1):

Check your **functions.php** inside your theme folder.
It happened the same to me, redirecting to jqueryc.com...

Comment: nope, not that file but good answer, thanks. Problem was in my header.php

Answer (score 1):

How strong are your admin credentials to access the site? If they are relatively weak an attacker could guess your credentials. It may also be possible there is DNS poisoning of the host's servers - something they would have to fix. If you type in your URL and it loads your site AND then a malicious site then this is not the likely cause.

Also look through your site code for iFrames that may have been added by attackers that will load malicious sites / content. These do not require malware on the server, just a line or two of HTML code.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found the problem. See my answer below: It is a malicious(harmless) script the theme developer put there to get traffic to his site: Got it in the header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be, that the new theme contains garbage? Perhaps, there's something to configure. However, I'd never try to fix a compromised website, just restore a backup of all files and the database. Then, you may try to reproduce all that by uploading that theme again, while having your backup ready. Themes could contain more than just some style definitions. Of course, changing credentials is recommended in case of doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I used [jsunpack](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/) and it deobfuscated to the following:

```
 //document.write (s)  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://themenest.net/platform/script/track?d=undefined&r=undefined&c=905"></script>
```

You can see the [permanent report](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/?report=977a09413c0f4909ce7dec82a9af68ed3dc85924) for yourself. This looks like a tracking bug and a privacy problem for your users. I'd remove it and probably not use any more themes from that site, personally.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. Obviously that code does not belong on any site...Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -3):

Select all files.
And remove it...

Then upload your files there again..
Hope this will work fine also..